# How to use dayjs in typescript

Tags: typescript, dayjs

```js
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs'
```

- debug success
- build `Cannot call a namespace ('dayjs')`, `TypeError: dayjs__namespace is not a function`

try another

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
```

- build success
- debug `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

How can I do?

Comment: Neither of those are typescript errors. Are you using some other kind of build system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using dayjs in my typescript project like below

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
:
this.date = params.get('date') ? dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
```